# A syntactic property of computing systems: is non-coding DNA universal?

Tags: computability, reference-request, semantics, normal-forms, syntax

One of the surprising aspect of the genome for lay-people is that it
contains important [non-coding DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncoding_DNA) parts, which does not mean that they are
all useless. I never paid so much attention to the fact, until very
recently, when I realized that the same is apparently true of all
computing formalisms I can think of ... but maybe I forgot some, which
is part of my question.

If you consider finite state automata, you can always add an arbitrary
finite chain of unreachable states, which may be read as the Gödel
number of whatever statement you care to add to the FSA,
whether a copyright statement or a complete formal proof that it
recognizes a regular expression in some a priori chosen formalism.

But the same is actually true of CF grammars, of Turing Machines, of
Post Correspondence Problems, of lambda-expressions, of Primitive
Recursive programs, or of Partial Recursive programs, to name some of
the more important computing formalisms. Actually I cannot think of a
computing formalism that does not have that **syntactic
feature**. This is also true of programming languages, often as an
official syntactic feature called *comment*, which is not strictly
necessary, but does save time and space.

I recently used the property to prove (hopefully correctly) that all
[primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) can be implemented as a recursive set of
Turing Machines. This may not be a very deep result, but my understanding from that proof is
that the phenomenon is very general and may have other consequences.

To be precise about definition, I think one could call **non-coding part
of a formalism instance** those parts that can be identified by a uniform
decision procedure as computationally irrelevant.

**Question:**
Is the property as general as I make it? Has it been analyzed more
thoroughly, including causes (is it unescapable?), consequences, and
theoretical or practical uses? Does it have a name?

I think that the property could somewhat be implied by general
theorems about computability. But why should that extend to very
simple formalisms like FSA.

My guess is that, given the above definition of non-coding part, it
may be that for simpler formalisms like FSA there is a uniform
recursive procedure that can remove all non coding parts: that
procedure could be made part of the formalism specification, thus
contradicting my universality statement. But such a procedure would
not exist for a Turing complete formalism (Rice theorem?). And the fact remains that even the simpler formalisms we use are defined with this "comment" potential, even if it might be removable by a restriction to normal forms.

Comment: Is it as simple as "there infinitely many X for the same language"? Clearly, there is an X for every amount of gutter, and since it's irrelevant I can use all chunks of gutter of this size (i.e. encode). There *are* formalisms without this property; in recursion theory we have non-repeating numberings, for instance.

Comment: One possible answer is that in models of computation in which language equality is undecidable, there must be more than one encoding for infinitely many languages (since otherwise equality would be decidable).

Comment: @Raphael I do not think it is as simple as that. What are the non-repeating
numbering? How powerful are the formalisms that do not have the
commenting property. I am asking because it is easy to remove it for
finite automata or CF grammars.